# Ruby on Rails errors when generate project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, intellij-idea, rubymine

Use RubyMine(or IDEA with plugin, same errors) and, when i try to create new project and IDE start to generate files, get this

```
Error:[rake --prereqs] rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
D:/Dropbox/RubyProj/Test3/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
D:/Dropbox/RubyProj/Test3/Rakefile:4:in `require'
D:/Dropbox/RubyProj/Test3/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
D:/Dropbox/RubyProj/Test3/bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- sqlite3/2.1/sqlite3_native
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in `require'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
D:/Dropbox/RubyProj/Test3/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
D:/Dropbox/RubyProj/Test3/Rakefile:4:in `require'
D:/Dropbox/RubyProj/Test3/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
D:/Dropbox/RubyProj/Test3/bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
```

and this

```
    Error:Get available generators script executes with errors:
Error:DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
Error:C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.9-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.7.3/lib/bundler.rb:133:in `require'
Error:  from D:/Dropbox/RubyProj/Test3/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:146:in `require_application_and_environment!'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:133:in `generate_or_destroy'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `generate'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:40:in `run_command!'
Error:  from C:/tools/ruby213/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
Error:  from D:/Dropbox/RubyProj/Test3/bin/rails:4:in `require'
Error:  from D:/Dropbox/RubyProj/Test3/bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

How to fix it?
Installed last ruby(with chocolatey) and rails 4.1.6(with IDEA or RubyMine)

Comment: Have you tried creating the application the standard way with `rails new mysite` and see if you get the same error? This way you would know if its a problem with your machines setup or has something to do with Rubymine.

Answer (score 0):

it occurs linux too, in linux i must first run `sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev`. if you are in windows, in my exp, you only need to install sqlite from http://mislav.uniqpath.com/rails/install-sqlite3/